# Fill screen with ground texture nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm struggling to find a way to fill the screen with rows and rows of sprite nodes.

I can only currently get one solid line like so.

[image]

I want it so the code repeats itself so it fills below the current row, I've tried several things with no luck.

I am new to SpriteKit and iOS game development so I might be missing something obvious.

Below is my code, any help with be greatly appreciated.

```
let world = SKNode()
let ground = Ground()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
/* Setup your scene here */
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.6, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1)
self.addChild(world)
var groundPosition = CGPoint(x: -self.size.width, y: 600)
let groundSize = CGSize(width: self.size.width * 3, height: 0)
ground.spawn(world, position: groundPosition, size: groundSize)


}

class Ground: SKSpriteNode, GameSprite{
var textureAtlas: SKTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "ground.atlas")

// Property named groundTexture to store current ground texture: 
var groundTexture:SKTexture?
func spawn(parentNode: SKNode, position: CGPoint , size: CGSize) {
    parentNode.addChild(self)
    self.size = size
    self.position = position
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1)
    //default to the the mud texture
    if groundTexture == nil {
        groundTexture = textureAtlas.textureNamed("grass")
    }
    // Repeate the texture
    createChildren()
}

//Builds nodes to repeate the ground
func createChildren() {
    if var texture = groundTexture{
        var tileCount:CGFloat = 0
        let textureSize = texture.size()
        let tileSize = CGSize(width: 25, height: 15)
        // Build nodes until we cover the screen
        while tileCount * tileSize.width < self.size.width{
            // randomly chooses the texture that will be used
            let random = arc4random_uniform(50)
            if random < 25{
                texture = textureAtlas.textureNamed("grass")
            }else{
                texture = textureAtlas.textureNamed("mud")
            }
            let tileNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
            tileNode.size = tileSize
            tileNode.position.x = tileCount * tileSize.width
            tileNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
            self.addChild(tileNode)
            tileCount++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not changing the y property of the position anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Nick for commenting, do you have a rough idea of where to adjust the y position? This is the bit i'am stuck on.

Comment: Before looking into optimization, there should probably be an outer loop outside your current while loop that changes the y every time you've completed a horizontal pass for _n_ number of times (based on the size of the scene).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this instead of `createchildren()` :

// numbers of rows needed to fill the screen.

```
var num = self.frame.height / groundTexture.size.height
```

// method to fill the screen with repeated grass :

```
    for no in 2..num {

       var groundTextRep = groundTexture.copy

       groundTextRep.position = CGPoint(x: groundTexture.position.x, y: (groundTexture.position.y * no)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this Comment Fady i managed to work this out but my way was no where as neat as this lol, i'll give it a go and ill let you know how i get on.

Comment: @ConorHolman The best thanks for this community is to select the Fay Lateef answer as the correct answer by flag it, I see you 've never done in your threads, please set it so the other users can be find correctly the solutions.